# How to programmatically extract SQL Server table schema to construct SQL Server CE?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

As stated in the title, how can I programmatically create a SQL Server CE 4.0 from a remote SQL Server?

I want my application to allow users to delete the `.sdf` and create a new one based on the new remote database schema when there is a database schema update. And then download relevant data for offline use.

I already read up about the `SqlCeEngine` part, but I am not good at SQL Server CE queries - seem to give many syntax errors when trying out in Management Studio.

I also tried Microsoft Sync Framework Snapshot synchronization but it feels too bulky and the Local Cache Database modifies my database schema and generates a lot of junk I do not need. Maybe a lower level solution like querying information.schema or something may work better?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout DMO.  Using managed code, you can enumerate objects like tables, columns on the sql server side.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174487(v=sql.80).aspx

Here's a tutorial to get you started:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SMO_Tutorial_1.aspx

Concerning the data, one option is the bcp utility

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337544.aspx

Those are good starting points if you want to extract and create a new database.  For mirroring/sync, probably not a good path.  If it's read only data on the client and you jst want to update the local data, then you can just extract again and throw away the old 'data cache'

Answer (score 0):

You can use my scripting API and command line tools to do this: http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com - see for example this blog post: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-use-exportsqlce-to-migrate-from.html

Answer (score 0):

This may be a more up to date way using SQL only:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```